# How to shell_exec program_linux_i386 from PHP

Tags: php, x86, centos, x86-64, shell-exec

I downloaded (mdldec_linux_amd64) and (mdldec_linux_i386)

and placed them somewhere in cPanel / Files Manager / HTML folder

How to call this program from Call.PHP ?

I try something like below

```
shell_exec ("mdldec_linux_amd64 parameter1 parameter2");
```

can someone help me on this?

Comment: Did you get any errors or information which shows why your code didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing commands from php is not recommended, this might bring security issues. If you don't have an option here are 2 examples:

You should try to use the full path for the file you want to execute:

```
shell_execute("/usr/local/mdldec_linux_amd64 parameter1 parameter2");
```

Assuming that the file is the /usr/local folder

Also you can use exec and get the last returned line from the executed command. and also the full output

```
$output = array();
$lastLine = exec("/usr/local/command",$output);
```

And you might be able to debug better and have more information